# Ternar operator for 3 cases

Tags: c++

Sorry for this question..
I want to user ternar operator for and if else if else statement.
I want to ask if there is need for brackets as in **example 2** or it's ok the **example 1** ?
I know both compiles..
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int x2;
    if (x == 14)
    {
        x2 = 10;
    }
    else if (x == 14)
    {
        x2 = 140;
    }
    else
    {
        x2 = 0;
    }
    
    int x = 14;
    // example1
    auto x2 = x == 10 ? 100 : x == 14 ? 140 : 0;
    // example2
    auto x2 = x == 10 ? (100 : x == 14 ? 140 : 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: 1. Example 2 shouldn't even compile, 2. Things get really messy with nested ternaries, so at that point you should really just be using if/else.

Comment: `if (x == 14)` there's no x at that point so your code doesn't compile

Comment: ok, thanks is there any issue with Example1 ? or can be safely used ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I for one think that it's more clear without parentheses...

Answer (score 3):

Well adding parenthesis is just to increase clarity in the ternary operators. It should not affect your code flow *if they are put at the right place*.

Here there are no brackets, and it would still mean the same as below:

```
x2 = x == 10 ? 100 : x == 14 ? 140 : 0;
```

Here I put as many brackets as I could

```
x2 = (x == 10) ? (100) : ((x == 14) ? (140) : (0));
```

While these brackets are for clarity to the user, over using them could make it complicated to read,
My take would be to write it as below

```
x2 = (x == 10) ? 100 : ((x == 14) ? 140 : 0);
```

And all of these would essentially mean

```
if (x == 10) {
    x2 = 100;
} else {
    if (x == 14){
        x2 = 140;
    } else {
        x2 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey OP... could you tell me why unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you need even more compares you could do this (I made this an excercise for myself, so not really an answer):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <map>

template<typename type_t, unsigned int N>
constexpr type_t n_ary(const type_t& value, const type_t& default_value, const std::pair<type_t, type_t>(&options)[N])
{
    for (const auto& option : options)
    {
        if (value == option.first) return option.second;
    }
    return default_value;
}

int main()
{
    auto x= 8;

    // x = is your value
    // 0 = default value if nothing matches
    // per pair, first is the value to match, second is value to return
    auto x2 = n_ary(x, 0, {{ 10,100 }, {14,140}, {8,42}, {6,36}});
    assert(x2==42);
}
```